# Processor threads, Tomcat Threads, Java Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, threadpool, processor

**Can anyone explain me the difference between processor threads, tomcat threads and Java threads and their relationship?**

**So from what I know:**
The processor has a certain number of cores. It I have a dual core machine it will offer me 4 threads.
Tomcat has also a number of threads (which have a default value of 200)
And Java can also have a number of threads, which can be created every time I need one or can be taken from a ThreadPool which can be configured my be.

**My understanding of what happens when I make a call to an endpoint is like this (assuming I have a dual core -> 4 threads):**

1. I make a call to "/myEndpoint"
2. My call will use one of the processors threads -> the processor thread sends the request to one of Tomcat's threads -> which will also send that request to MyApplication's main thread
3. My application has the following options:
   a. Solve the request by itself and give the answer back to the Tomcat thread which in turn will return it to the processors thread.
   b. Send the request to **one of the threads created by** me or **one of the threads in the ThreadPool configured by me**, wait for an answer and send the answer back to the Tomcat thread which in turn will return it to the processors thread. FIRST QUESTION IS AT THIS POINT: Is the thread **createdByMe** / **threadPoolThread** using one of the other 3 processor threads that are left available ? (my logic says yes)

**The problem comes when I start thinking about a huge number of requests at the same time:**

1. 300 people make a call to "/myEndpoint"
2. Since my processor has only 2 cores (4 threads) I guess it will take 4 requests at a time and the 296 remaining requests are put in some kind of queue till the first 4 ones are processed.
3. Those four requests are sent to Tomcat which also sends them further to the Java app.
   SECOND QUESTION IS AT THIS POINT: If the Main thread of my app sends the request to a thread **createdByMe** / **threadPoolThread** how is that thread supposed to work since all of the 4 threads of my processor are used at step number 2?

I read lots of questions around here and also on other pages but did not manage to find something to present the full life cycle of a request (or at least to make it more clear) and also some examples of multiple request (the 300 requests example with a lower number of processor threads) (processorThread -> TomcatThread -> JavaThread -> TomcatThread  -> processorThread )

Some graphical representation of the lifecycle would definitely make it more clear to understand. I would appreciate any information regarding this problem and correction of the information presented in the rows I have written

[The kind of diagram that would be useful for an explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vENGO.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

As of 2021, all commonly-used implementations of Java based on the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) code base implement a Java [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) as a host [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) thread. Each Java thread in the JVM corresponds to a thread in the OS. (This may change in the future with [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) technology.)

Every Java app starts with one thread. Apache Tomcat is a Java app. Tomcat starts with one thread. Tomcat is then free to spawn additional threads as it sees fit.

While I do not know Tomcat’s internals, generally every request coming into a such a server is assigned to a thread. In that thread a response is built. Generally, the web server portion (*Catalina* in Tomcat) maintains one thread dedicated to listening for incoming requests. That thread dispatches each request to a new or recycled thread for processing. If the web server is becoming overwhelmed with requests, the server may elect to hold them briefly in a queue as you mentioned. Or the web server may choose to cancel the request, sending back the appropriate HTTP error to the web client.

Basing Java threads on host OS threads has pros and cons, trade-offs. One of the cons is that the practical limit on the number of threads is relatively low. (Project Loom, mentioned above, seeks to remedy this, allowing for millions of threads at a time.)

I suspect that what you are calling « processor thread » is really mislabeling the main Java thread of a server such as Tomcat. As mentioned above, that main thread likely launches a Java thread to listen for requests. That listening thread launches additional threads to handle requests. On Java Servlet based servers, that request-processsing thread invokes your Servlet code. Your Servlet code may choose to spawn one or more threads, likely through an executor service. Or, if on a [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE)-compliant server, your Servlet code may choose to use the built-in [Jakarta Concurrency](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/concurrency/) features to more easily accomplish tasks on additional threads.

Note that these are all Java threads: Tomcat main thread, request-handling threads, additional background threads. Your terminology seems to imply these are different kinds of threads. But they are not different kinds, at least not on a web server and Servlet engine built in pure Java such as Apache Tomcat and Eclipse Jetty.

You said:

> send that request to MyApplication's main thread

While we as Servlet programmers find it convenient to think of our Web app as an actual app, it is not actually an app. Your Web app is simply zero, one, or more threads, each handling an incoming request. There is no “main thread” of a web app. Each request mapped to a particular Servlet cause another thread to run that servlet’s code. One object in memory represents your particular Servlet, many threads may be running that very same Servlet code of yours with each thread serving a client.

You said:

> . Send the request to one of the threads created by me or one of the threads in the ThreadPool configured by me, wait for an answer and send the answer back to the Tomcat thread which in turn will return it to the processors thread.

Your code may choose to spawn threads. You should make that choice cautiously. A Servlet environment is already highly-threaded by definition. Expecting many simultaneous users in deployment should discourage you from running lengthy tasks on many threads. In contrast, with an in-house server for a department having a small number of users, you may have no concern about reaching the practical limits.

And running a single task on a single thread while the first thread waits is a waste use of resources, as the first thread could simply have done the work itself.

You said:

> Is the thread createdByMe / threadPoolThread using one of the other 3 processor threads that are left available ?

Any threads launched by you are just Java threads, just the same Java threads as being used by your Servlet engine. All the Java threads (nowadays) map one-to-one with host OS threads. When those threads execute, how much time they get to execute, and on which processor they execute, is determined by the JVM and the host OS. That behavior will vary from one computer to another. That behavior will vary at runtime, depending on ever-changing runtime conditions. That behavior is not under our control as Servlet coders.

You said:

> SECOND QUESTION IS AT THIS POINT: If the Main thread of my app sends the request to a thread createdByMe / threadPoolThread how is that thread supposed to work since all of the 4 threads of my processor are used at step number 2?

A) No such thing as a main thread of your web app. There is a thread assigned to each incoming request.

B) You generally would not be passing the request off to additional threads. *You already have a thread dedicated to processing the request*, the thread assigned by the Servlet engine. That is one of the main jobs of a Servlet engine, to manage the threads assigned to requests. If you decide to spawn threads, it would be for work such as running three different database queries in order to build a complex report as part of the response going back to the user.

C) Threads are routinely suspended from running on the CPU core. The JVM and host OS work together to freeze one thread in order to give another thread more time to run. There is overhead to this process, which is one reason to avoid overburdening your machine with too many threads. (Again, this may change when Project Loom arrives, as the JVM will be handling the scheduling of “virtual threads” ([fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))) without much involvement from the host OS. This will make threading very “cheap”, meaning much faster while using less memory more efficiently.)

---

Servlet engines such as Apache Tomcat and Eclipse Jetty may, under the covers, being doing specialized handling of threads to optimize heir performance. I ignored that fact in the discussion above because we as Servlet coders have no perception of that optimizing and no control over it. Conceptually, I believe the discussion above is sound through not necessarily entirely accurate depending on these potential optimizations.

Furthermore, such optimizations may change under Project Loom technology in the future. All of this is transparent to us as Servlet coders. That is the point of Servlet technology, to shield us Servlet coders from these nitty-gritty details of implementing a server.